# Calling java from PHP exec

Tags: java, php, apache-flex, exec

I am doing the following in PHP:

```
exec('java -jar "/opt/flex3/lib/mxmlc.jar" +flexlib "/opt/flex3/frameworks" MyAS3App.as -default-size 360 280 -output MyAS3App.swf');
```

When I run this from the command line, it runs fine and finishes in a second or two.

When I run this command from PHP exec, the java process takes 100% CPU and never returns.

Any ideas?

I have also tried running the above command with '/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true'.

I am running Mac OS X 10.5.5, MAMP 1.7, PHP 5.2.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug specific to the PHP stack MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/).

Turns out any invocation of the JVM following fails under MAMP, e.g.:

```
exec('java -version');
```

The fix is to prefix the command with

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="";
```

Also I realized there's no reason to use that method of invoking mxmlc.

So here's the final, working command:

```
exec('export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=""; mxmlc MyAS3App.as -default-size 360 280 -output MyAS3App.swf');
```

Comment: If you're still not getting any output, add 2>&1 in the end i.e. exec('java -version 2>&1');

Answer (score 2):

I manage to get this to work togheter with MAMP. The solution was to include the:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="";
in the exec call:

$argss = "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"\"; /usr/bin/java -jar /Applications/yourjarfile.jar";
$resultXML = exec($argss, $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why your using the mxmlc jar file to compile your flex application? have you tried using the executable or an ant task, instead?

Maybe the compiling is taking too long so that your PHP script times out?

Comment: It's not a timeout. He's said it takes 2 seconds to compile it from the command-line.

Comment: when I try compiling with ant i get the same result

Comment: also when i try compiling with the mxmlc executable i get the same

Answer (score 0):

Exec is always tricky, on any language :-)

Try to:

- use background execution (add &
  symbol at the end)
- use shell_exec instead
- specify the full path to
  java executable (may be the one
  available to PHP is not the one you
  need?)
- run a simple HelloWorld java
  app to see if the problem is in Java or
  in mxmlc specifically

It's strange that java takes 100% CPU. I cannot explain it with any common mistake made when using exec()... try to send it a SIGQUIT to dump the threads, then read the dump -- may be you'll figure something out.