# webserver crash with exec in php

Tags: php, exec, wampserver

i am try to convert some file with exec in php and get the return . i do this and this is work so successfully but if i run it for more than 10 times, the webserver (wampserver) get crash and i must restart server to continue ?
please let me know what is the problem if you know .

System : wampserver version 2.0 on windows xp and 2003 server .

thanks

Comment: Please use updates to your question to add information or bounties to bring attention to it instead of providing "answers".

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs for a more detailed description of the crash. That should point you in the right direction.

Another thing to check is the memory usage of the script. If your server is overrunning its memory limits, the PHP module may be crashing the entire server.

Comment: i am check logs but i can't find an important result it's only this error in apache logs :
[Sat Jun 27 02:28:02 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Jun 27 02:28:15 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/persianCloudComputing/white.PNG

Comment: the only thing is unusually it's in my processes in taskmanager . if the convert files be successfully "cmd.exe" closed automatically after that, but if convert get worse the cmd.exe not closed and it remain in processes and i force it to close with "end process" but wampserver can not work until i restart it completely ?

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble with the server's stability, and not with the programming part of the problem. I think this would be a question better suited to serverfault.com. In any event, what processes is cmd.exe launching? Can we see the PHP code that is converting your file?

Comment: i use it to convert flv to avi and it work successfully if i run it directly in cmd for any times but i have problem in php, also i think more people have this problem to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278868/calling-java-from-php-exec) is this true ?!!!! any idea ?