# PHP exec() function not working

Tags: php

I am using macbook-pro, and i am executing this php script using apache server, but i am not getting the output of exec() function. It is not even showing any error. Can anyone tell me how to get the output. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   echo "<h1>Hello, PHP!</h1>";
   echo exec('java -version');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sure you do not get the expected return from `exec()`? This sounds a little like you did not read the functions documentation. It does _not_ return the output of the command you execute.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278868/calling-java-from-php-exec

Comment: yeah, i have read the documentation and exec() returns the last line of the output, the above script is working on online php compiler and it is giving the java version as output. but it is not working on my computer neither it is giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   echo exec("java -version");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

output

> java version "1.7.0_45" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   24.45-b08, mixed mode)

You can copy and paste the code here ans you'll get the output.
[Click Here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php)

Comment: i know about this website and i have tried here but i want to execute it in my system. It is not working on my computer

Comment: Change the single quote to double